# Are objects constructed inside a for loop destructed after their respective iteration or after the whole loop has finished?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm creating a huge number of objects inside a parallel for loop to perform slight variations of the same task. When constructed, the objects allocate some vectors. The loop looks like this:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (long long unsigned i=0; i<nparam; i++) {
    Foo x;
    x.do_task();
    x.save_results();
}
```

It caused the computer to run out of memory. Is this because each of the `Foo` objects isn't destructed until all iterations of the loop are finished. This could be the problem because if I have 100,000 iterations to do and each object uses a vector with 10,000 doubles, that would require 8 GB (right?), which is a lot.

On the other hand, if each `Foo` object is destructed after its iteration of the loop, I have to look for a memory leak somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Are objects constructed inside a for loop destructed after their respective iteration" - Yes.

"or after the whole loop has finished?" - No.

Objects are destroyed at the end of the scope they are declared in. The body of a `for` loop is a scope (scopes are denoted by curly braces `{}`), so for each iteration a new object is constructed and destroyed.

Comment: It's worth noting that this has nothing to do with OpenMP; it's a property of C++ which is unaffected by the presence of OpenMP pragmas on the loop.